# textbox value from client side in code behind?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I'm writing a website that is fully dynamic . means all controls are made by Response.write , no I have a problem , that after page load I want to get value of text boxs which made dynamically in code behind , but its not received by Request.Form , here is my code :

```
Private Function userconf() As string
    Dim script As String

    Dim conString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("sqlexpress").ConnectionString
    Using con As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(conString)

        Dim com As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM clientamount WHERE Mode <> 1 ", con)


        con.Open()

        Dim resultid As String
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = com.ExecuteReader()
        Try
            While reader.Read()

                RenderBuyForm = RenderBuyForm + "<div><input id='tx" & reader("ID") & "' type='text'  />" & reader("avrageamountunit") & "<input id='txd" & reader("ID") & "' type='text'/>"
            End While
        Finally

            reader.Close()
        End Try


    End Using


    Return RenderBuyForm
End Function
```

and this function loads in page_preload event :

```
   Protected Sub Page_PreLoad(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreLoad
    userconf()


    End If
End Sub
```

and also in html page I have

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <%=RenderBuyForm%>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

    </form>
```

at least I try to read textboxes value are in html page now in Button1_Click event:

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click



    For Each row As DataRow In tabel1.Rows

        Dim a As String = Request.Form("tx" & tabel1.Rows(0)("ID") & "")

      label1.text = a 


    Next
End Sub
```

but a is returning Nothing  . can I ask you help me in this issue ? how can I read these textboxes value from client side in code behind ?

Comment: It is the name attribute which will be used upon form submission. Your inputs seem to miss this attribute. I must say that you don't seem to be using asp.net webfoms the right way. It is mainly based on controls declaration and control objects manipulation, postbacks, etc... . If you want to generate your markup, you may have a look at MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will also need to add to

```
RenderBuyForm = RenderBuyForm + "<div><input id='tx" ....
RenderBuyForm = RenderBuyForm + "<div><input name='tx' & reader("ID") ..
```

in the userconf().

Comment: there wasn't any need for javascript , it was solved by adding name attribute to html input , again thanks for your advise